# Can't upcast interface to extended interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, upcasting, typecasting-operator

I have 2 interfaces

```
public interface A {
 method1();
 method2();
}

public interface B extends A {
  method3();
  method4();
  :
}
```

I am in need of converting (upcasting) B to A in one of class. But so far I could not figure out how do I do that.

Assume "methodWhichReturnB" is method which returns B.

```
public class C {

  public void method10() {
     A a = methodWhichReturnB; // din't work
     A aa = (A) methodWhichReturnB // din't work          
  }
}
```

I am getting compilation error "Inconvertible types; cannot cast B to A".

Is there way I can upcast B to A ?

Comment: why would you want that? About all it would achieve is making sure certain functionalities are no longer available.

Comment: Since `B extends A` assigning an instance that implements `B` to a variable of type `A` should work. If it doesn't then something is off in your code, i.e. "cannot cast B to A" would indicate that `B` does _not_ have `A` in its hierarchy. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It works on my side. You're missing to share something I think. Maybe some name clashes?

Comment: Thanks folks. @MatteoNNZ - there was one name clash which was causing this. Got it fixed. Thanks.